# Skip the cell and the content of a DataTemplateColumn in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to tab through a datagrid, but at the end of the row I have a template column that is taking in a tab. I have set the datagrid cell style to not focusable and istabstop = false, but it still seems to be going into the content. Is there a property for a TemplateColumn that will have it be skipped by tabbing completely?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" in the CellStyle for that column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting IsTabStop=False for the control you have used underneath your templated column.